# What are the differences between `pipx` and `pip --user`?

Tags: python, pip, pipx

I have tried to install any python packages on `Ubuntu:24.04`, but found I cannot do that as in `22:04`

[PEP668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) said it is for avoiding package conflict between system-wide package and user installed package.

But what's the differences between using `pipx` and `pip --user`? And why the `--user` option not work, it also installs packages to the user's own home.

exampe:

```bash
$ pip install setuptools --user
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

But if I do that with `pipx`:

```bash
$ pipx install pip

No apps associated with package pip or its dependencies. If you are attempting to install a library, pipx should not be used. Consider using pip or a similar tool instead.
```

I am really confused with current rules.

How can I manage my user global environment now? And how can I use latest `pip`(not linux-distro version) and other packages by default for current user?

My Enviroment:

```
FROM ubuntu:24.04

# add python
RUN apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python-is-python3 pipx

USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
```

Comment: Plase focus on one question only. Perhaps this should simply ask about the difference between pip and pipx, and you should have a separate question about how to install setuptools (with more details about what you tried and what's already on the system).

Comment: @tripleee, my main question is how to get  `user global env` back. `setuptools` or `pip` is just an example.

Comment: Then `pipx` is obviously entirely out of scope; but then probably better to accept the answer you already received and ask a new question with the proper focus. Details to include: Which Python version, how exactly did you install it; how exactly do you conclude that `setuptools` isn't already installed?

Comment: @tripleee, I think `pipx` is not out of scope, system will tell user to use `pipx` whatever package user install by `pip install --user xxxx`. I know I can install it by `apt` but it is not for create a user env but system env

Comment: @tripleee, I added my system information above

Comment: Again, probably accept the answer you already received for the question in the title, and ask a new question which focuses on the actual installation question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip --user` is a function provided by pip, and pipx is a software package. Ubuntu can guarantee that the packages you install using pipx will not pollute the system environment, but pip does not have this guarantee.
Additionally, you should install setuptools using `apt install python3-setuptools`.

Comment: So how can I manage my user global environment now? For example, the debian packge pip is not always the latest version. How can I keep my user env's pip updated? And `--user` option is won't pollute the system environment but is forbidden by ubuntu.

Comment: Your requirements seem irreconcileable. Your distro can guarantee that exactly the version they provide as a package will work and be compatible and appropriately configured for your system. If you want the bleeding edge, don't use anything from the package manager, and maintain your own Python toolchain yourself. `pyenv` is a fairly popular tool for this.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your distro's Python but want to contol `pip` and `setuptools` yourself, a virtual environment might be a suitable solution. You could create a single global venv for everything if you  wanted to, or use one per project directory.

Comment: You can try building Python yourself from python source code.